# Two constructors, which is default?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

Okay I got a pretty simple assignment.

I got these two constructors for class Person:

```
Person( const string &, const string &, const string & );
Person( const string &, const string &, const string &,
const string & );
```

I got 4 default values

which of these are going to be the default constructor? is it always the one with most arguments or how does it work?

Comment: This belongs on [so], as this question is not asking for a code review but for an explanation of a C++ feature.

Comment: my bad, can't delete it now it seems though

Comment: If what you say is true and both have all default arguments, it will be ambiguous.

Comment: Neither. Typically the default constructor takes no arguments. For instance, `Person() {}`.

Comment: I asked a moderator to move it over to Stack Overflow, but this may take some time. Just be aware [what this site is for](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) the next time you ask a question

Comment: If he reads this he can just delete it, i already created one over there :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about explaining a C++ feature

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard

> 4 A default constructor for a class X is a constructor of class X that
>   can be called without an argument.

From your post it is not clear what default values you are speaking about. Neither of your declarations is the default constructor.

If you are speaking about default arguments as in the declaration

```
Person( const string & = "", const string & = "", const string & = "",
const string & = "" );
```

Then this declaration is a declaration of the default constructor because it can be called without any explicitly specified argument.

It is interesting to note that the same constructor can be a default constructor and a non-default constructor at the same time. At least the C++ Standard does not say anything that forbids this.

For example

```
struct A
{
   A( int x );
   int x;
};

A a1; // error: there is no default constructor

A::A( int x = 0 ) : x( x ) {}

A a2; // well-formed there is a default constructor.
```

Comment: But what if both have default arguments in the declaration? wont it be ambiguous then?

Comment: @Sumsar1812 Yes it will be ambiguous.

Comment: Ah i see, my teacher did set this question up a bit tricky, he even said there was a 50/50% chance of getting this right ;). Thanks I can see how it works now

Answer (score 6):

Neither of these two constructors is the default one.

A default constructor is one that you could invoke with no parameters - either because

- the constructor has no arguments, or
- all of its parameters have default values.

Both constructors in your example require that parameters be passed to them, so neither of them is a default one.

Answer (score 3):

A default constructor is a constructor that either has no arguments or it has some but all of them provide default values. In your case, if both of your constructors have all of their arguments with default values, then a call like

```
Person p;
```

will be ambiguous. Think about it: which one is to be called?

Answer (score 2):

A default constructor is a constructor that either has no arguments, or if it has arguments, all the arguments have default values. So neither one of these could qualify as default constructor.

Comment: So if there was 4 default values, then the last one would be the default constructor?

Comment: In short: a default constructor is a constructor which can be called without passing any arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Both the constructors will be matched only when the signature of the call statement matches. The default constructor is always the constructor with no arguments

```
Person(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ask which could be called; that depends on how you create object.

For example;

1 - First is called

```
Person person = new Person("a","b","c");
```

2 - Second is called

```
Person person = new Person("a","b","c","d");
```

Comment: Not if all are defaulted. Then the first is ambiguous (and neither works with the `new` in there).

Comment: Can't we create two or more constructors. As I know we can create and use it with different values. Isnt it function overloading principle? If we specify the one when creating object, the related one must be called.

Comment: Yes, of course, but not with all defaulted parameters like the OP stated in the question (or I could be wrong about that because the question isn't overly clear).